# Let $AB$ be the chord of circle $k$ with a centre $O$. Through an arbitrary point $P$ on chord $AB$ is constructed a line $OP$....

Tags: geometry

[image]Let $AB$ be the chord of circle $k$ with a centre $O$. Through an arbitrary point $P$ on chord $AB$ is constructed a line $OP$. The altitude on $OP$, constructed through $P$ cuts the tangent lines of $A,B$ in $M,N$. Prove that $P$ is the middle of $MN$.

I've added a diagram, it's my first time using GeoGebra so I apologize for its' rough edges. I've managed to prove $OBPN$ is a cyclic quadrilateral, so I think that it'd be possible to prove $OPM$ and $OPN$ being congruent without proving the congruency of $OAN$ and $OBM$. Mark the angles $OBA$ and $OAB$ (who are equal as $OA=OB$) as $x$, then, we know that the angle $ABN$ is $90−x$ as it's the angle between a chord and tangent (chord-$AB$ and tangent through $B$) so it's equal to the peripheral angle on the opposite side of the chord, which we know is half of the central angle above the same chord, in this case $AOB$ which is $180−2x$, so the peripheral angle above the same chord is $90−x$ so $ABN$ is also $90−x$. We can now notice that $OBN=OPN$ so they're peripheral angles above the chord $ON$ which means that $OBNP$ is a cyclic quadrilateral.
Using this, I've now gotten that $NOP=90−x$, but I'm not sure how to prove $MOP=90−x$ (proving them equal would provide us with the congruency we need).

Comment: Hi there, sure, which software should I use?

Comment: try to show that triangle OAN and OBM are congruent and use that to prove that triangles OPN and OPM are congruent as well. I tried the first part, but I am currently stuck why angle AON and BOM should be equal. Maybe you see this.

Comment: Any that you prefer, GeoGebra is a popular one and if you draw a good diagram, you will probably see the solution too :)

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll update this post once I've drawn up a diagram.

Comment: I've added a diagram, it's my first time using GeoGebra so I apologize for its' rough edges. I've managed to prove $OBPN$ is a cyclic quadrilateral, so I think that it'd be possible to prove $OPM$ and $OPN$ being congruent without proving the congruency of $OAN$ and $OBM$. Mark the angles $OBA$ and $OAB$ (who are equal as $OA=OB$) as $x$, then, we know that the angle $ABN$ is $90-x$ as it's the angle between a chord and tangent (chord-$AB$ and tangent through $B$) so it's equal to the peripheral angle on the opposite side of the chord, which we know...

Comment: is half of the central angle above the same chord, in this case $AOB$ which is $180-2x$, so the peripheral angle above the same chord is $90-x$ so $ABN$ is also $90-x$. We can now notice that $OBN=OPN$ so they're peripheral angles above the chord $ON$ which means that $OBNP$ is a cyclic quadrilateral

Comment: Using this, I've now gotten that $NOP=90-x$, but I'm not sure how to prove $MOP=90-x$ (proving them equal would provide us with the congruency we need).

Comment: @Cookie btw you made really good progress. But your comments about OBPN being cyclic etc. should be mentioned as an edit to the question. Please note not everyone reads comments before deciding to downvote / upvote / vote to close a question.

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely do that in my next question.

Comment: You can do it even now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Please note that $POAM$ and $PONB$ are cyclic quadrilaterals.

So if $\angle OAB = \angle OBA = \theta$, $\angle OMN = \angle ONM = \theta \implies OM = ON$ and as $OP$ is perp to $MN$, $P$ bisects $MN$.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer, could you share how you proved $POAM$ is a cyclic quadrilateral?

Comment: $\angle OAM = \angle OPM = 90^\circ$ so they add to $180^\circ$.

Comment: Haha, I figured this out but didn't see it on my diagram. Thanks for the help.